# Storage server web services RemoteTenantManagerService/getAllTenants

Tags: wso2, integration

I'm using method `getAllTenants` from class `RemoteTenantManagerServiceStub` to get all tenant from server and result is an error message as `org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement {http://api.user.carbon.wso2.org/xsd}active` it's seems to be a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you try invoking the admin service directly with SoapUI and see what are the differences.

Comment: I test it in SoapUI and it works. I suppose that problem is in parsing of response but i'm not sure.

Comment: The error says Unexpected subelement.

Comment: @ycr I can read also :D. But why? parser can't parse element `active` that exists in `Tenant` class. and namespace instead of `http://api.user.carbon.wso2.org/xsd`  shouldn't be `http://tenant.core.user.carbon.wso2.org/xsd`

Comment: This can be a bug, You can rise a JIRA for this, Try the latest release this might be fixed https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases

Comment: @GVArt Make sure you have the same stub jar version in both application and server. What is your SS version?

Comment: @Bhathiya I checked this, version is 4.3.3 on both sides . SS is 1.5.0
Problem remain

Comment: Can you try replacing the wsdl here with the one from your SS server, and build a new stub and try?
https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/tree/carbon-identity-4.3.3/service-stubs/identity/org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub/src/main/resources

Comment: @Bhathiya done, but this nothing change, problem is not in wsdls. Problems is in parser, it can recognize filed `active` as a valid field, but this field should exist in tenant object. review that row from Exception message `Unexpected subelement {http://api.user.carbon.wso2.org/xsd}active`

Comment: No, it's the other way around. The object has this 'active' field, but stub doesn't know about it. Hence 'Unexpected' subelement. That's why I assume it's a problem with the stub. It also explains why SOAP UI works for you.